# log http webresponse between specific status codes

Tags: vb.net

I have following code to perform certain task for specific error codes

```
Using resp As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Select Case (resp.StatusCode)
        Case CType((resp.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.Accepted And resp.StatusCode <= HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous), HttpStatusCode)
            'do something
        Case CType((resp.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.BadRequest And resp.StatusCode < HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError), HttpStatusCode)
            'log something
        Case CType((resp.StatusCode > HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError), HttpStatusCode)
            'show something
    End Select

End Using
```

However none of the case statements are called.

Answer (score 0):

Well your `CType`s are just dumb.
As is the rest of that code.  Pick up a book, take a class, peruse MSDN.

```
Using response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse
  Select Case response.StatusCode
    Case Is <= HttpStatusCode.Accepted, Is <= HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous
      ...
  End Select
End Using
```

Comment: Dan-o: Thanks for your suggestion. You may want to take it up with the dev team at Microsoft as this was the auto correct that VS-2010 did for me and I went with their code suggestion.